# launching Android Chrome Browser through Appium Automation using emulator is throwing error and chrome browser is not launched properly

Tags: appium-android, android-browser, appium-desktop, appium-java, android-chrome

[Screen when the code is run and chrome is launched`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKDyq.png)

## Appium server is also running and even the chrome browser is launched but displays blank white screen after launching

Below is the error while running the code.

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found. SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementationSLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details. Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: timeout: Adb command timed out after 30 seconds  Host info: host: 'IN-HVKMHS3', ip: '192.168.29.3' Build info: version: '4.9.1', revision: 'eb2032df7f' System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_361' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:automationName=UiAutomator2, browserName=Chrome, appium:chromedriverExecutableDir=C:\Users\gjsr\Downloads\Drivers, appium:device=Android, appium:deviceName=emulator-5554, platformName=ANDROID, appium:platformVersion=12}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {automationName: UiAutomator2, browserName: Chrome, chromedriverExecutableDir: C:\Users\gjsr\Downloads\Dri..., device: Android, deviceName: emulator-5554, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 12}}] Capabilities {automationName: UiAutomator2, browserName: Chrome, chromedriverExecutableDir: C:\Users\gjsr\Downloads\Dri..., device: Android, deviceName: emulator-5554, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 12}    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:133)     at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)     at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:194)     at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)  at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:80)  at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)  at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:117)   at ecolab.connect.base.BaseTest.main(BaseTest.java:45)
```

`Below is the code :`

```
package ecolab.connect.base;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.net.URL;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileBrowserType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class BaseTest
{
    public static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException 
    {
        
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();
          capabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutableDir","C:\\Users\\gjsr\\Downloads\\Drivers");
        
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
                capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","12");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
         try {
        driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.goolge.com");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();
    }
        
        
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `chromedriverExecutable` capability instead of `chromedriverExecutableDir`